# sdk instalation problem in eclipse (ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-sdk

sir i want to load android SDK in eclipse but i get error.

second point is- i also get error while creating android virtual device.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'my'
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Comment: have you tried suggested error message option .  try to launch using `emulator -avd  <avd_name>  -force-32bit`

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse-based Android SDK is lamentably no longer supported; the official environment is now Android Studio (based on IntelliJ). While it might still be possible to install the Eclipse-based SDK, instructing you how to do so would be a bit like trying to give you advice on where to find leaded gasoline.

Comment: Sir your command is ok. But Sir I want to set it - "Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT "to 'true' in your environment. How can I do this. Please provide me step.